# Where should I write the code to add a label?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add a label. Where should I write the code to add the label?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var x = 20.0
        var y = 100.0
        let width = 100.0

        let offsetX = 80.0
        let offsetY = 80.0

        for i in 1 ... 9 {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: width))
            button.tag = i
            button.setTitle("\(i)", for: UIControlState.normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: UIControlState.normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonPressed(button:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            self.view.addSubview(button)

            x = x + offsetX

            if i%3 == 0 {
                y = y + offsetY
                x = 20.0
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed (button:UIButton) {
        print("Button Pressed: \(button.tag)")
    }
}
```

Comment: in `viewDidLoad` you can add label just like you added the buttons, What's the problem?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad I recommend that you read stack overflow guide for asking questions. you are repeating same line three times and without any detailed explanation about your question.

Comment: CAn you help by writing code ?

Comment: let lblNew = UILabel((frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: width))
lblNew.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
lblNew.text = "Label Text"
lblNew.textColor = UIColor.black
view.addSubview(lblNew)

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with adding a label, if you couldn't find how to add a label by mentioned code snippet, you don't even have to add it...

Comment: But where i have to put this code , at what place ? Compiler is giving Errors.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad Your question makes no sense. You have posted code that clearly shows you creating buttons. Since you already know where and how to write code to create buttons, what issue are you having trying to create labels? You should update your question with specific details about whatever issues you are having when trying to create labels.

Answer (score 0):

```
let lblNew = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: width))
lblNew.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
lblNew.text = "Label Text"
lblNew.textColor = UIColor.black
view.addSubview(lblNew)
```

Comment: But where i have to put this code , at what place ? Compiler is giving Errors.

Comment: Inside viewDidLoad() You have to set x,y,width and height.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to add label. You can use the following code.

```
    let lblNew = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: width))
    lblNew.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    lblNew.text = "Label Text"
    lblNew.textColor = UIColor.black
    view.addSubview(lblNew)
```

If you want to add with every button. you can put inside the loop and change the values of x and y accordingly.